# "I, for one, don't know "

Tags: phrases, expressions

I am curious about the precise meaning of *for one* in the expression "I, *for one*, don't know."

This came up in a discussion about the amount of social efforts society should be willing to put in reducing CO2 emissions. In essence, my interlocutor said something like

> " given the limited precision of complex climate models, the uncertainties about future technological progress, and the doubts about the exact damages that would be caused by climate change if it were to happen as predicted, how much should we be willing to invest in reducing carbon emissions by say 1 ton? I, for one, don't know."

In this context, is the meaning "I, *for one*, don't know." closer from "As far as I am concerned, I would no dare saying that I have an answer to that question" or "In this case, I cannot answer this question", with *for one* indicating that the person has an answer to many other questions but not this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*for one*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/for-one) is an interesting idiom. It is used in several ways, predominantly to say that you believe your opinion or action is right, even if others do not

> The rest of you may disagree, but I, for one, think we should proceed with the plan.

It can also indicate a particular one of several [possibilities](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/for+one)

> I, for one, am not upset or ashamed; in fact, I feel very grateful.

or, as [one example](http://www.americanidioms.net/%28I%252fyou%252fhe%29-for-one), even if the *only* one

> And I, for one, welcome our new insect overlords!

This last use (first uttered in The Simpsons) has become mimetic, and was used to honor Watson, IBM's artificially intelligent computer system capable of answering questions posed in natural language.

Comment: Thanks. Any best guess of the signification in the context I mentionned?

Comment: @MartinVanderLinden - I think the speaker doesn't want to spend money to reduce responsibility for climate change. He is justifying this by saying, there are so many problems with this whole climate change science. Should we invest money we have for something that's not sure to be worth it? I, (against the better stance that I should), for one, don't know (even though the evidence is clearly there according to others.) Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

I have a slightly different answer, and this is supported by the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/one_1#one_1__193):

> **for one**:
>   used to emphasize that a particular person does something and that you believe other people do too.
>
> - *I, for one, would prefer to postpone the meeting.*

(Many people would like to postpone the meeting--and that includes me.)

Comment: Thanks. Any best guess of the signification in the context I mentionned?

Answer (score 1):

I, for one, means that I am speaking only for myself and sharing my view of something even if that is contrasting from other's idea.

> "I for one" is used to stress an individual's specified view about himself.

Eg: I for one, don't think it is a good idea.

This is reworded as

> "I don't think it's a good idea, but other may think it is."

A comment I read on a social network site,

> "Based on what I have learnt about science, the light from the closest stars take thousands of years to reach us, a star doesn't die in a couple days, which means I would have to look through a telescope for a VERY long time to witness the death of a star LIVE. Looking at a CGI version of it is fine, I don't have a problem with that, but should it be portrayed as though a star is dying as I type this or died recently and this is a video recording of the event? I for one don't think so."